# Can't Update state after fetch request

Tags: reactjs, ajax, graphql

I'm trying to make an app where I fetch data from a Graphql API, and update state after fetching, but after the successful request I'm getting the data but I can't update state with that data. when I console log the response data it's showing the array with required data but when I update state and console log the state it's showing empty array.

I need to update the state to use it in the component, when i'm doing this it's throwing error that currList is undefined.

here are pictures of code and console.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [search, setSeach] = useState("");
  const [currList, setCurrList] = useState([]);

  const fetchShips = async () => {
    const response = await request(gql`
      {
        ships {
          name
          home_port
          image
        }
      }
    `);
    console.log("request response", response.data);
    setCurrList(response.data);
    console.log("currlist:", currList);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchShips();
  }, [currList]);

  const Searchitems = (event) => {
    setSeach(event.target.value);
    setCurrList(
      currList.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.includes(search) || item.home_port.includes(search);
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <header></header>
        <div className="body">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="search"
            value={search}
            onChange={Searchitems}
            className="input"
            placeholder="Search Ships"
          />
          <p>Total Count: {currList.length}</p>
          <div className="ships">
            {currList.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <Ship
                  key={index}
                  name={item.name}
                  port={item.port}
                  img={item.image}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It has been set but setCurrList is async and you can see the currList state by logging it in a useEffect

Comment: try log it into useEffect

Comment: `useEffect(()=> {console.log(currList)},[currList])`

Answer (score 2):

the State is Updated just not when the code is running that's why it logs that the state is an empty array, try to console.log it once again and you will see that there is something in the List.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal, everything is happening asynchronously. React will trigger a re-render once your currList is updated and you will get its new value. If you want to listen to this change, you have to use useEffect with currList as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("List is updated", currList);
}, [currList]);
```

Comment: I need the state to render the components, how do I do that? when I use the above code it's throwing error "currList.map is not a function" and "cannot read property of undefined ( length ) ".?

Comment: first, regarding the code you shared, the useEffect should have an empty array as a dependency because you want  to call the fetchShips only for the first render useEffect(() => {
    fetchShips();
  }, []);

Comment: Do you see the error after or before typing on the search input?

Comment: I'm seeing the error before I type in the search input, the error is showing on component render

Comment: can you see this line executed : console.log("request response", response.data); ? What is being displayed in the console ?

Comment: well, I just saw the console you shared before, the next line should be : 
setCurrList(response.data.ships);

Answer (score 1):

The function fetchShips has closure over the currList state variable that blongs to specific render call, so when you log it after calling setCurrList it shows you the previous state not the updated state, you can log it in the useEffect to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. I couldn't find efficient solution but my solution saved me anyway.

I used useRef instead of useState.
Try this:

```
  const currList = useRef([]);

useEffect=(()=>{
const fetchShips = async () => {
    const response = await request(gql`
      {
        ships {
          name
          home_port
          image
        }
      }
    `);
    console.log("request response", response.data);
     // setCurrList(response.data);
if(response)
    currlist.current = response.data

    console.log("currlist:", currList);
  };
fetchShips()
// Also as far as I know ,you should use useEffect like this
},[])
//... codes

return(
//... codes
 currList.current.map(...

)
//... codes
```

Before using useRef, try to define your fetchShips function  inside useEffect so maybe you don't need my solution.

Why is not efficient my solution for your case?
When you want to update your currList data, useRef does not trigger re-render. Even if your data updated, you cannot see it on your screen.
So setCurrList(currList.current) can save you but as I said earlier it may not efficient way.